# ¿Compo puedo agregar mi PHP a mi formulario de Angular?

Tags: php, angular, formularios

Descripcion:
Basicamnete lo que quiero hacer es que mi php funcione con un componente especifico en angular pero no lo e logrado hacer pero no se como integrarlo a mi componente de angular ya que al dar click en el boton de mi HTML no ocurre nada,mi carpeta de PHP lo tengo a la altura de src es donde tengo mi archivo en PHP ademas investigue sobre PHPMAILER que al parecer era lo que me faltaba pero realmente no se si funciona ya que el boton no hace su accion el formulario lo cree con bootstrap

1.HTML

```
<hr />
<div class="fondCo" id="cont">
  <h1 class="title">CONTACTO</h1>
  <iframe
    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3757.9128616220587!2d-99.09239668526104!3d19.63102278677195!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x85d1f3e4b24733e3%3A0xebdf57a30d1a290e!2sDel%20R%C3%ADo%20Solutions%20Outsorsing%20(DRS)!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2smx!4v1602608863216!5m2!1ses-419!2smx"
    width="1518"
    height="200"
    frameborder="0"
    style="border: 0"
    allowfullscreen=""
    aria-hidden="false"
    tabindex="0"
  ></iframe>
  <br />
  <br />
  <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="saveData()" novalidate>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 input-group-sm">
        <label for="inputNames">Nombres:</label>
        <input
          formControlName="Name"
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="inputNames"
          placeholder="Nombre..."
          required
        />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 input-group-sm">
        <label for="inputSurnames">Apellidos:</label>
        <input
          formControlName="Surnames"
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="inputSurnames"
          placeholder="Apellidos..."
          required
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 input-group-sm">
        <label for="inputEmail4">Correo:</label>
        <input
          formControlName="email"
          type="Email"
          class="form-control"
          id="inputEmail4"
          placeholder="name@example.com"
          required
        />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 input-group-sm">
        <label for="inputSurnames">Asunto:</label>
        <input
          formControlName="Affair"
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="inputAffair"
          placeholder="Asunto..."
          required
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Textarea1  input-group-sm">Mensaje:</label>
      <textarea
        formControlName="txt"
        class="form-control"
        id="Textarea1"
        rows="2"
        placeholder="..."
        aria-required
      ></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="recap">
      <ngx-recaptcha2 #captchaElem [siteKey]="siteKey" formControlName="RES">
      </ngx-recaptcha2>
    </div>
    <button
      id="btn"
      type="submit"
      method="POST"
      [disabled]="myForm.invalid"
      class="btn btn-dark"
    >
      <i class="fab fa-telegram-plane" style="color: #f37b00"></i> Enviar
    </button>
  </form>
  <div class="desc">
    <p>
      <i class="fas fa-map-marked-alt" style="color: #f37b00"></i>
      Coacalco Edo.Mex,Estado de México.
    </p>
    <p>
      <i class="fas fa-phone" style="color: #f37b00"></i>
      Oficina: (01 55) 91 54 23 758
    </p>
    <p><i class="fab fa-whatsapp" style="color: green"></i> 55 22 93 83 09</p>
    <p class="ult">
      <i class="fas fa-envelope" style="color: #f37b00"></i>
      ventas@enterprise.com.mx / drs@enterpise.com.mx
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

2.PHP

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';
require 'PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


$destiny = "example@gmail.com";

if(isset($_POST['btn'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['inputNames']) && !empty($_POST['inputSurnames']) && !empty($_POST['inputEmail4']) && !empty($_POST['inputAffair']) && !empty($_POST['textarea1'])){
        $Names = $_POST['inputNames'];
        $Surnames = $_POST['inputSurnames'];
        $email = $_POST['inputEmail4'];
        $Affair = $_POST['inputAffair'];
        $Msg = $_POST['textarea1'];
        $msgCOMPLETE = $Msg . "\nAtentamente: " . $Names . $Surnames;

        $header = "From: $email" . "\r\n";
        $header.= "Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n";
        $header.= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
        @mail($destiny, $Affair, $msgCOMPLETE, $header);
        if(@mail){
            echo"<script>alert('Enviado exitosamente')</script>";
        }else{
            echo"<script>alert('No se ha enviado correctamente')</script>";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como punto de partida, vas a necesitar un servidor web Apache (como [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)) para que procese el archivo PHP.

Cuando vos logres levantar el XAMPP, como punto importante, probablemente tengas que hacer y manejar un ruteo en tu servidor PHP

Mira este documento: [Como redireccionar rutas a archivos en PHP](https://www.taniarascia.com/the-simplest-php-router/)

Posteriormente, una vez levantado tu Apache, y configurado las ruta (Supongamos http://localhost:8080/email)  vas a ser capaz de acceder y utilizar esa ruta desde Angular de la siguiente forma

```
constructor(private httpService: HttpService){}

public saveData():void { 
  const values = this.myForm.values;
  this.httpService.post(`http://localhost:8080/mail`,values).subscribe(data => {
   console.log("Data guardada correctamente");
  }, err => {
   console.error("Error",err);
   })
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias,Disculpa la tardanza al contestarte

Comment: No hay por qué. Si necesitas ayuda cualquier cosa, comentame!